# Conectando Genexus ao SQLserver - passo a passo

Tags: genexus

Tenho um projeto em **Genexus 9 gerando em Visual Fox 9** com base de dados em .DBF.
Gostaria de migrar para banco SQLServer.
Alguém teria um passo a passo para conectar o Genexus ao banco SQLServer?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

1. Você deve estar gerando para o gerador VFP GeneXus, agora você precisa gerar para o gerador VFP C/S (server client)
2. Você deve criar uma fonte de dados ODBC no Windows que se conecta ao servidor SLQ. Na parte do armazenamento de dados, adicione o nome dessa fonte de dados definida

Talvez este artigo seja útil para você levar em consideração alguns parâmetros ao migrar:

https://www2.genexusnet.com/gxpintranet/hgxpp001.aspx?1,14,132,O,S,0,,10056